# SQL error sign (single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I got this "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

and my Query is

```
Select contact_ID from contact where (

Select b.Contact_ID from company a, contact b where a.Company_ID =  b.Company_ID 
and a.IS_ACTIVE <> 'N' and b.IS_ACTIVE <> 'N'
and a.CREATED_DATE >= '01-Jun-2013') =
(
Select b.Contact_ID from company a, contact b where a.Company_ID =  b.Company_ID 
and a.IS_ACTIVE <> 'N' and b.IS_ACTIVE <> 'N'
and a.CREATED_DATE < '01-Jun-2013');
```

I don't know why this is not working. Please help me out

Comment: Can you describe what you want the query to do?  I think it might have other problems besides the one you mention.

Comment: sure sorry about bad script. This is the first time I am doing SQL.

Comment: Find the duplication of contact id comparing one table with CREATED_DATE >= '01-Jun-2013' and one table CREATED_DATE < '01-Jun-2013' and both table need to have the same conditions a.Company_ID =  b.Company_ID and a.IS_ACTIVE <> 'N'

Comment: so I have two tables and link them with contact_ID

Comment: Do **not** rely on implicit data type conversion `'01-Jun-2013'` is a String, not a date. Depending on the client settings that can fail miserably when Oracle tries to convert that into a date. Always use `to_date()` with a format mask (or ISO literals like `DATE '2013-06-01'`) and try to avoid month names, use numbers. Otherwise this can be the cause of very subtle and hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    Select contact_ID from contact where Contact_ID in 
        (
         Select b.Contact_ID from company a 
         inner join contact b 
         on  a.Company_ID =  b.Company_ID 
         where a.IS_ACTIVE <> 'N' and b.IS_ACTIVE <> 'N'
         and a.CREATED_DATE >= '01-Jun-2013' 
         ) ;
```

edit:

more simpler without `IN` clause.

```
     Select b.Contact_ID from company a 
     inner join contact b 
     on  a.Company_ID =  b.Company_ID 
     where a.IS_ACTIVE <> 'N' and b.IS_ACTIVE <> 'N'
     and a.CREATED_DATE >= '01-Jun-2013' ;
```

Comment: I am not sure this cover a.CREATED_DATE < '01-Jun-2013' condition

Comment: Why bother using the `in`?  The subquery looks like it produces the right list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select contact_ID 
from contact 
where (
Select b.Contact_ID 
from company a, contact b 
where a.Company_ID =  b.Company_ID 
and a.IS_ACTIVE <> 'N' and b.IS_ACTIVE <> 'N'
and a.CREATED_DATE >= '01-Jun-2013') IN
(
Select b.Contact_ID 
from company a, contact b 
where a.Company_ID =  b.Company_ID 
and a.IS_ACTIVE <> 'N' and b.IS_ACTIVE <> 'N'
and a.CREATED_DATE < '01-Jun-2013');
```

Comment: But this code quality is pathetic... Definitely need to be rewritten

Comment: Still gives me an error ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Removed sub select and replaced with union.

```
Select b.Contact_ID 
from company a, contact b 
where a.Company_ID =  b.Company_ID 
and a.IS_ACTIVE <> 'N' and b.IS_ACTIVE <> 'N'
and a.CREATED_DATE >= '01-Jun-2013'
union
Select b.Contact_ID 
from company a, contact b 
where a.Company_ID =  b.Company_ID 
and a.IS_ACTIVE <> 'N' and b.IS_ACTIVE <> 'N'
and a.CREATED_DATE < '01-Jun-2013');
```